# Where is my mod rewrite fail?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have got url

> ipaddr/opensys/base/

and some other similar, like

> ipaddr/opensys/base/something.php?olol=yep

I want to remove from url "opensys" and display there "center", i want to see this links working:

> ipaddr/center/base/

and

> ipaddr/center/base/something.php?olol=yep

I did it with symlinks, but it was not good, because system is very difficult and with symlink some plugins not works, I want to do it with .htaccess only, after it all will be ok.

My htaccess is:

but links, which i want to see is not working, why?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/opensys/base/(.*)$ /center/base/$1 [L]
RedirectMatch 301  ^/opensys/base/(.*)$ /center/base/$1
```

Redirect works good, but i see 404, rewrite rules is not working. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to handle the /center/base/ now in the .htaccess file as you must be handling opensys earlier. Something like this -

```
RewriteRule ^/opensys/base/(.*)$ /center/base/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/center/base/(.*)$ /index.php?args=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /opensys/(base/\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /center/%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^center/(base/.*)$ opensys/$1 [L,NC]
```